# How to even floor varnish without sanding the whole floor

Tags: painting, floor

We rent a flat with a rustic Victorian look. They've removed the carpets and varnished the wooden planks under them. Looks very rough but also nice. The problem was that they also varnished over some shoe marks. I wanted to remove those so I sanded parts of the floor and varnished again. Unfortunately, I did not measure the amount of varnish to apply. So now there are places on the floor where the varnish is quite thick and glossy.

My question is how do I reduce that thickness without sanding the whole floor again? Can I sand partially and apply something else? Or just sand with something less invasive?

Answer (score 1):

You should sand those thick spots including some of thin spots. If your shoemarks are size 5x5", lightly sand around such as 10x10" and re-varnish again all over the sanded area. You'll even it out.